# how to change url rewrite wordpress from single post

Tags: wordpress

I use wordpress 4.9.5, I am trying to rewrite URL in my custom post type: posts and store. This is the existing URL I am able to access:

With single post name: Single post name with url:

```
DOMAIN/single-post-name.html
```

When i have other link:

```
DOMAIN/single-post-name.html?hi=123&name=name-child-2
```

I want to access the URL like this:

```
DOMAIN/single-post-name/123/name-child-2.html
```

Can somebody help me. Thanks all

Comment: You can change the URL from edit post. If you like to add `/` then you can use the Permalink plugin to override the URL.

Comment: No, my idea, i want to change many ID from ?hi=
with some story,
single-post-name?hi=1&name=name-child-1
single-post-name?hi=2&name=name-child-2
single-post-name?hi=3&name=name-child-3
single-post-name?hi=4&name=name-child-4
single-post-name?hi=n&name=name-child-n
if auto change or redirect to new url